# Text disappearing in Safari when adjacent image animated with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, text

The text in the main list of projects [on this page](http://paulcalver.staging.wpengine.com/projects/) is disappearing when you roll over/off the text quickly.

I can't figure out why it's only happening in Safari? (Its fine in Chrome/Firefox... and even in IE9)

Thank you!

```
    function projectImageRollovers() {
    $('#projects li a').mouseenter(function() {
        // if($('ul#work-menu').hasClass('desktop')) {
        if($(window).width() > 768) {
            $(this).parent().stop().find('.project-thumb').fadeTo("fast", 0.4);
        }
    });
    $('#projects li a').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).parent().stop().find('.project-thumb').fadeTo("fast", 0);
    });
}
projectImageRollovers();
```

[image: Example of missing text]

Comment: Is there a reason you're using JS for this instead of plain CSS?

Comment: Ah, that's a good question, I guess I didn't think it was possible

Comment: I've added a simple CSS-only solution that might work for you, hopefully fixing your Safari issue in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try plain CSS instead of Javascript:

```
#projects li img {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

#projects li:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```